# Doctrine2: how to map 2 entities

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I seem to be having a lot of trouble mapping 2 entities in Doctrine2.

I have a class User, a class Person and a class Candidate.
Both Person and Candidate extend from User, in a "Is an"-relation, so both Person and Candidate should have a oneToOne relation with User.
Both Person and Candidate have a property "userid" which is the foreign key that should map to the userid from User.

This all seems rather simple but I can't get it to work.
When looking at the documentation of Doctrine (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html?highlight=DiscriminatorColumn#single-table-inheritance), I cannot use Mapped Superclasses because I want user to be an entity as well. And I cannot use Single Table Inheritance because I do not have an DiscriminatorColumn.

I have all the necessary tables in my PostgreSql database, and I'm using yml for the necessary mapping files.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @MappedSuperclass may works for you even if the it isn't an entity (For repository you can make an AbstractUserRepository that PersonRepository and CandidateRepository will extends. If you really want an entity for user (for reasons you didn't make clear) then just specify a simple one-to-one relation..

Comment: Your answer is confusing, the documentation states that using a MappedSuperclass is only possible when the superclass is not an entity. And I do want my User to be an entity, because I need that object for security reasons.
About specifying a one-to-one relation, everything I have seen about that always points to a "has a"-relation, instead of a "is an"-relation, which I want. Person extends User, it does not have a property User.

Comment: Yes using MappedSuperClass allows you to have two class but backend there is only one table (so only one entity). Doctrine is "copying" the columns from the @MappedSuperClass to you child class. For the relation type, there isn't a "is-a" relation in common DBMS, so there are converted to "has-a" relation.

Comment: So as I said in my original post, I cannot use a MappedSuperClass because I have 2 tables, and I also need it to be like that because I need to have both entities.

Comment: Fine then just make a one-to-one relation (http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10317701-MySQL-inheritance)

Comment: But doesn't that mean that I have to make User a property of Person and Candidate? And That is just something I'd like to avoid.
But if I'm getting this right, there is no way to do what I want without using a MappedSuperlass or using my Userclass as a property of the subclasses? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes i do not see any other solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 designing problems with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279392/doctrine2-designing-problems-with-inheritance)