# Doctrine2 designing problems with inheritance

Tags: doctrine-orm, mapping

I am currently setting up a new application and decided to use doctrine2 as an orm.
I am new to doctrine2, and having quite some difficulties getting my design the way I want it.

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have the following classes:

```
class User {

    protected $userid;
    protected $role;
    protected $lang;
    protected $email;
    protected $disabled;
    ...
    + getters and setters
}

class Person extends User {

    protected $personid;
    protected $name;
    protected $firstname;
    protected $company;
    protected $functiontitle
    ...

    + getters and setters
}

class Candidate extends User {

    protected $candidateid;
    protected $name;
    protected $firstname;
    protected $title;
    protected $birthdate;
    ...

    + getters and setters
}
```

Both Candidate and Person inherit the User properties, but have their own set op specific properties.

In the postgresql database I currently have a similar set up, 3 tables, with each their set of specific columns.

Now I would like to map this using yaml, and want all 3 of the classes to be accessible as entities.
I also don't want to have to duplicate a lot of fields in my database.
How can I accomplish this?
I've been looking for solutions for days but haven't come up with anything working.

If what I am trying to do is not possible then please explain what my options are, and why this isn't supported.
Without an ORM it seems that I could easily add foreign keys to candidate and person to join with the user table, but I can't get that to work with doctrine.

This is the yaml file I currently have to set it up as a Class Table Inheritance:
User:

```
MyProject\model\User:
    type: entity
    table: `user`
    id:
        userid:
            column: userid
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            comment: ''
            id: true                  
    fields:
        role:
            column: role
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        email:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''        
        disabled:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
            comment: ''
    InheritanceType: JOINED
    DiscriminatorColumn:
        name: discr
        type: string
    DiscriminatorMap:
        person: Person
        candidate: Candidate
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Person:

```
MyProject\model\Person:
    type: entity
    table: person
    fields:        
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        firstname:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        company:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        functiontitle:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: null
            fixed: false
            comment: ''
        ...
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at D2 inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: I have, and currently have it set up like this, but I now get an error that the fields (i.e. "role")  of my userentity do not exist as a column in my person-table. Which is correct because I don't want them in my person-table because they are in my user-table.

Comment: Update your question with your stripped down mapping files.  Well that was quick.  For three tables, you want to use class table inheritance, not single table inheritance.  Single table will put everything on one table.

Comment: Done, the Candidate mapping file is similar to the Person mapping.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use role as a standalone column as well as the discriminator column.  Not going to work.  Name your column discr or something besides role.  This is an internal doctrine thing and you can't get around it.

Comment: I'm still getting the error that 'role' is not a column. When running orm:schema:update --dump-sql
I get the suggestion to drop all of my user columns, and add them in person and candidate. But that would be duplicating the same columns in two tables, what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid injury, sit on your hands before reading further.  Don't want to give yourself a concussion with a face palm.

...

ready?

...

Lower case the first letter of inheritanceType, discriminatorColumn and discriminatorMap.

Drop the schema and rebuild.

I am assuming that you already changed the discriminator column to discr.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did facepalm myself however ;-)